# Awk matching array value to string not working

Tags: arrays, awk, split

I realize there are a number of similar questions....   Hopefully I can get some more insight here.

I need to match a key from keywords.tsv, to a sentence in data.tsv.   If the keyword exists anywhere in the sentence I want to print out both to a new file.  If there are two keywords in the same sentence it should be printed twice.

keywords.tsv

```
color>color                                                                                                                    
colour>color    
expiry>expiration    
expiration>expiration
```

data.tsv

```
something>more                                                                                                                 
What is the expiry date of your credit card?>more    
The credit card colour is blue and the expiry date has passed.>more    
This card has a current expiration date.>more
```

desired result:

```
expiration>What is the expiry date of your credit card?>more    
expiration>The credit card colour is blue and the expiry date has passed.>more                                                 
color>The credit card colour is blue and the expiry date has passed.>more    
expiration>This card has a current expiration date.>more
```

I've tried amoung a lot of things:

```
 awk -F "\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next}    
 {    
   split($1,b,",");    
   for (b2 in b) { if(b[b2] == a[$1]) {print a[$1], $0}    
   }    
 }    
 ' keywords.tsv data.tsv
```

I seem to be having a hard time figuring out how to access the values of the array from file1 among other issues.   Help appreciated!

Comment: Is data in your `keywords.csv` tab delimited or `>` delimited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that `>` is meant to be a tab character.

Your main issue seems to be with separators: you don't want to split on commas, you want to split on sequences of whitespace:

```bash
awk '
  BEGIN {FS = OFS = "\t"}
  NR == FNR {kw[$1] = $2; next}
  {
    n = split($1, words, /[[:blank:]]+/)
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      if (words[i] in kw) print kw[words[i]], $0
    }
  }
' keywords.tsv data.tsv
```

```
expiration      What is the expiry date of your credit card?    more
color   The credit card colour is blue and the expiry date has passed.  more
expiration      The credit card colour is blue and the expiry date has passed.  more
expiration      This card has a current expiration date.        more
```

Comment: Awesome!    Just what I needed!